# LLVM - convert const void * to LLVMValRef

Tags: casting, llvm-clang, gcc-warning, llvm-gcc

I need to cast const void * to LLVMValRef ,like this

```
const void * context;     
args[0] = LLVMCastPtrToBoolType((void *) context);
```

I get the following warning.

> warning: cast from type ‘const void*’ to type ‘void*’ casts away qualifiers

Comment: you are always going to get that warning, unless you turn it off... (const void *) is a promise that nothing is gonna mess with that data... then you give it to something that can mess with it... if you just need the value then just use the value... you can copy from const to non const, but it is different memory...

Comment: thanks for  your time @GradyPlayer